# Basis and Subspace of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let H be a subspace of a vector space V, and B = {u,v} a basis of H. Determine whether or not {u+v, u−v} is a basis of H.

I'm not sure how I would go about this problem. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What field is $V$ a vector space over?